# JPA Query is different than generated sql query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have this JPA Query definition in Spring repository

```
  @Query(value="select rd.contractID as contractID, rd.gicCode as gicCode, count(rd) as ticketNo" 
      + " from RawData rd" 
      + " where rd.contractID is not null and ((rd.contractCostObject is null and rd.domestic = true) or (rd.mirrorSVO is null and rd.domestic = false))"
      + " group by rd.contractID, rd.gicCode")
```

but the generated SQL query is that one

```
select
    rawdata0_.contractID as col_0_0_,
    rawdata0_.gicCode as col_1_0_,
    count(rawdata0_.id) as col_2_0_ 
from
    RawData rawdata0_ 
where
    (
        rawdata0_.contractID is not null
    ) 
    and (
        (
            rawdata0_.contractCostObject is null
        ) 
        and rawdata0_.domestic=true 
        or (
            rawdata0_.mirrorSVO is null
        ) 
        and rawdata0_.domestic=false
    ) 
group by
    rawdata0_.contractID ,
    rawdata0_.gicCode
```

As you can see the brackets are changed, and I believe the conditions are not the same in the two query.
Is it a bug?
using hibernate with spring with postgresql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `and` operator has precedence over the `or` operator.

- *conditionA and B or C and D*

is equivalent to

- *(conditionA and B) or (C and D)*

Apply this rule to your query, and the real result is similar to:

```
((rawdata0_.contractCostObject is null) and rawdata0_.domestic=true)
or 
((rawdata0_.mirrorSVO is null) and rawdata0_.domestic=false)
```

Exactly what you want. The query generated by JPA is correct.